# How to call a function in a C# DLL from another C# DLL in the same folder

Tags: c#, .net, dll

We are 2 teams (2 different vendors) working on developing 2 different C# DLLs.
The 1st DLL on which I am working, has to call a public function in the 2nd DLL developed by the other team. The function will NOT be a COMVisible function.

We have agreed upon some method signatures. The 2nd DLL will be placed in the same folder as the 1st DLL.

Whenever the other team releases a new version of the 2nd DLL, I want to just replace the file in the folder without the need to recompile my DLL, or register the other DLL using regasm, etc.

How should I write my code to invoke the function in the 2nd DLL? Preferably, if there is a solution without using Reflection, I will prefer that.

Further Background:

Both the DLLs will be shipped as part of an application. I do not want to have a static reference to the 2nd DLL in the 1st DLL, as finally I want to generate 2 DLLs to be shipped. The objective is that if later on, the other team wants to change the DLL, they can simply replace their DLL in the user installation without needing me to recompile my DLL.

Thanks.

Comment: If you know the DLL name why don't you just reference it?

Comment: If I reference, and the 2nd DLL later changes, will .NET automatically call the updated DLL in the same folder? Sorry, I have never done this before

Comment: You can simply replace a referenced dll as long as the api has not changed and they are not signed.

Comment: @Crowcoder, How does .NET framework go about looking for the 2nd DLL. Will it always look first in the same folder as the 1st DLL?

Comment: Yes, the 1st DLL will just invoke the 2nd. The 1st doesn't care if it is a different version.

Comment: @AllSolutions, read up on assembly resolution. Generally, you add a reference and the dll will output to the bin folder. But that is not the only option.

Comment: @Matt Rowland, Crowcoder, Can you post some helpful links about the order of steps in assembly resolution.

Comment: Just reference it in your .csproj file.

Comment: So what is the problem here? .NET was designed with DLL versioning in mind so that it won't balk if the referenced dll is updated,

Comment: Ok. Looks like its a pretty silly question. Should I just delete the question? :)

Answer (score 1):

MEF might be what You are looking for :

> The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating lightweight, extensible applications. It allows application developers to discover and use extensions with no configuration required. It also lets extension developers easily encapsulate code and **avoid fragile hard dependencies**. MEF not only allows extensions to be reused within applications, but across applications as well.

[Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)

Eventually you will be able to load *Components* from folder

```
// Load parts from the available DLLs in the specified path using the directory catalog
var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directoryPath, "*.dll");
// ...
```

Take a look at this Tutorial :

> Its basic purpose is to plug-in components to an already running application

[An Introduction to Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188054/An-Introduction-to-Managed-Extensibility-Framework)